# BN inside object

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I'm trying to send a BN to a Solana Program, but the account it's never set as intended. When the BN is sent as an another independent argument works fine.

```
    const created_at = new BN(Date.now());

    console.log(created_at);

    const worldData = {
      version: "1",
      owner: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      created_at: created_at,
    } as any;
```

Output

```
<BN: 18ae8740241>

Your world {
  version: '1',
  owner: PublicKey [PublicKey(6mxf...UAgE)] {
    _bn: <BN: 55ce...94df>
  },
  createdAt: <BN: 0>,
}
```

Rust:

```
#[program]
pub mod game_contracts {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_world(ctx: Context<InitializeWorld>, world: WorldData,) -> Result<()> {
        let world_account: &mut Account<'_, WorldAccount>  = &mut ctx.accounts.world;  

        world_account.version = world.version;
        world_account.created_at = world.created_at;
        world_account.owner = *ctx.accounts.owner.key;

        msg!("World initialized");
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeWorld<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = owner, space = 8 + 1024)]
    pub world: Account<'info, WorldAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct WorldAccount {
    pub version: String,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub created_at: i64,
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Default)]
pub struct WorldData {
    pub version: String,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub created_at: i64,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor expects you to provide the arguments in camel-case on the client side. So, when you are providing the value of `created_at`, use camelcase:

```
const worldData = {
      version: "1",
      owner: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      createdAt: created_at,
    } as any;
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: To catch this kind of type error, you can export the structs in your IDL as types like: `export type WorldData = IdlAccounts<typeof IDL>["worldData"];`

Comment: @BrunoBarros accept the answer if it resolved your query and do take the advise of Whiteseal. It's much better to work with the values when they are defined.

Comment: Done. And thanks for the advise, will do that.